# Checkbox refresh Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to have a series of items and my CheckBox is not updating (does not change state).

```
 Widget materialRow(
      String title, String pago, String text, double width, bool bandera) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
    
        Checkbox(
          value: bandera,
          onChanged: (bool newValue) {
            
            setState(() {
              bandera = newValue;
            });
          },
        ),
        Container(
          height: 180,
          width: width * 0.70,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              border: Border.all(color: Utils.colorgreen)),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  title,
                  style: Utils.styleGreenTitle,
                ),
                Text(pago),
                Text(text),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Only in the build method I invoke the function 3 times

```
  materialRow(
                      "Gratuita",
                      "",
                      "Veras anuncios debes en cuando y solo podras agregar un oficio o profesion",
                      width,
                      checkPlease),
```

I am sending the same variables for both invocations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the variable you're changing when you trigger a rebuild with `setState`. You're likely being confused by the widget being built within a function instead of directly in the `State`.

When you do `bandera = newValue;`, you're setting the **argument** `bandera` to `newValue`. You're not actually changing the variable stored in the `State`. So `bandera = newValue;`, is doing very little for your application. On the next rebuild, the value will just be overwritten again with the value of `checkPlease`. This might not have been an issue if this were an `Object` instead of a primitive `bool` as it would have been passed by reference and, with the right implementation, it would work out.

So what you have to do instead is to set the `checkPlease` variable. This likely is stored outside of the `build` and `materialRow` functions, which allows it to survive rebuilds.

Change

```dart
setState(() {
  bandera = newValue;
});
```

to

```dart
setState(() {
  checkPlease= newValue;
});
```

An alternative:

In addition to passing a `bool` to the `materialRow` function, pass a callback that does

```dart
setState(() {
  checkPlease= newValue;
});
```

to the `materialRow` function. This would be used if you for some reason don't have access to `checkPlease` from the `materialRow` function.

Ex.

```dart
void callback(bool newValue) {
  setState(() {
    checkPlease= newValue;
  });
}

//Add callback as a parameter
Widget materialRow(String title, String pago, String text, double width, bool bandera, Function(bool) callback) {
   ...
          onChanged: callback,
   ...
}

//Function usage
materialRow(
  "Gratuita",
  "",
  "Veras anuncios debes en cuando y solo podras agregar un oficio o profesion",
  width,
  checkPlease,
  callback
),
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap in StatefulBuilder to reload only the checkbox.For more info watch this
[How to use statefulbuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syvT63CosNE&ab_channel=Flutter)